# Is there a continue in minizinc or what is the alternative and how to convert if else in predicate?

Tags: minizinc

So like in python and other languages is there a continue statement in minizinc? below I have my minizinc if else statement how can I convert them into a predicate way ?

```
 if sum_neighbors(x,y) = 3 
       then grid[x,y]=1
    elseif sum_neighbors(x,y)=2 
       then grid[x,y]=grid[x,y]
    else grid[x,y]=0
    endif
```

How can I convert this into predicate form ? I tried the following but it does not work.

```
    (sum_neighbors(x,y) = 3 )
       -> grid[x,y]=1
   /\ ( sum_neighbors(x,y)=2 )
       -> grid[x,y]=grid[x,y]
    /\ (sum_neighbors(x,y)!=3 /\sum_neighbors(x,y)!=2) -> grid[x,y]=0
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Where in your example would the `continue` statement be used? Why can you not use the if-statement in MiniZinc as presented? It looks like it is (practically) valid MiniZinc

Comment: I want to use continue where i have used then grid[x,y]=grid[x,y], I want to optimize the code so it runs faster that's why I am thinking of predicates